# Save serializable object in persistent storage (android)

Tags: java, android, serialization, persistent-storage

I need to store a complex custom object in persistent storage in order to save the user's game progress in my app. The object and every object within this object implements `Serializable`

I call the use the loading and saving methods to pass the object between activities. I also call the `Save` method `onStop()` to save the object when the app is closed/destroyed. It works fine.

```
 public static Game Load(Context context){
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("player1.data");
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Game game = (Game) is.readObject();
        is.close();
        fis.close();
        return game;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("#Load", "creating new game - \n" + e.toString());
        Game newGame = new Game();
        return newGame;
    }
}


public static void Save(Context context,Game game){
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = context.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("player1.data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(game);
        os.close();
        fos.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("#Save", "Failed to save - \n" + e.toString());
    }
}
```

However, if the app is Force Closed or closed and destroyed, the `Game` object gets messed up. When relaunched, the application will load the `game` that was saved `onStop()`, but when the `game` object is changed/interacted with by the user through the application, my app force closes with the "has stopped unexpectedly" display message on the phone screen. From looking at the log, i know that when the `Game` object is being loaded on launch after being Force Closed / Destroyed, the `Load` method is returning `game` rather than `newGame`, so somehow the saving/loading process in between the Force Close messes something up.

On the log, I see this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

So, I am led to believe that something strange is going on with using `Serializable`, or I am incorrectly writing to persistent storage.

**My questions:** Do you see anything fundamentally wrong with my code? (keep in mind that this code does work, it just doesn't work under the Force Close circumstance)

I have been told to look into using `gson/JSON` (?) for my purposes; will this method have better results than `Serializable` and how can I use this?

**Update**: It seems that when Force Stop occurs, no methods are called - including the `onDestroy()` and `onStop()`. If this is the case, then why is my app not returning `newGame`? Looking at the log while Force Closing, a message that said something about "onSavedInstance not called," what is this?

I am getting the feeling that I should avoid `Serializable` entirely...

**onCreate snippet**

```
Game game;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    game =  LoadGame.Load(this); //LoadGame is the class which contains Save,Load methods

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    LoadGame.Save(this,game);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `onStop` method as well as the `onCreate` (or wherever you're calling `Load` from)? It seems the error is happening outside of the scope of the code you've provided.

Comment: @Khalos it has been added

Answer (score 1):

Tips, Serialization is awesome i use it all the time, the thing is, you are actually saving on a Thread that actually encountered a problem, are you expecting a magical call to `onStop()` ?  so either

- You call your save methods routinely on a different thread, so it keeps on saving irrespective of what happens.-after all its a game-
- You maybe add a try/catch to your code and catch certain exceptions and manually call a save method on a different Thread, well with this you need sick Encapsulation. This might not serve you well as errors like `noSuchMethod` etc, can not be caught so a force close might happen

either way your preference.

Comment: Well, even if i close the application via the device's square button and swipe right (clear processes) the onStop() should be called, correct? Even in this case, when my application is restarted after the process is killed, i get the same problem. So are you saying i should be saving my Serializable object in some other way?

Comment: square button? i thought that was the home button? and yes onStop() is supposed to be called but why clear processes? if you clear process is more like force stop you onStop indicates or triggered when the app is no longer visible to the user, and onpause is the first to be called when the device is about to loose visibility to the user, but from how you described what you just did, onStop was called but you cleared the app process? @MikeJamesJohnson

Comment: Yes, It is a square button on my LG g4. A lot of users kill apps like that in order to maintain good battery life. So, if my app fails when killed like that, then my app is worthless!

Comment: hmm, move that code to onpause instead of onstop and in your save method use  `context.openFileOutput` instead of ` context.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput` okay? and see if there is a change@MikeJamesJohnson

Comment: I figured out my problem. My game object made a reference to the MainActivity context in order to create a Toast. So when it was destroyed, it was trying to access something that didn't exist anymore